# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android

Не могу пофиксить данную ошибку вот код проекта:

Data class

```
data class RickAndMorty(
    val image: String,
    val name: String,
)
```

Api interface

```
interface RickAndMortyApi {

    @GET("/api/character")
    suspend fun getRickAndMorty() : Response<List<RickAndMorty>>

}
```

RetrofitInstance

```
object RetrofitInstance {

    val api : RickAndMortyApi by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://rickandmortyapi.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(RickAndMortyApi::class.java)
    }

}
```

CoroutineScope

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = true
            val response = try {
                RetrofitInstance.api.getRickAndMorty()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException, you might not internet connection")
                binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                return@launchWhenCreated
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "HttpException, unexpected response")
                binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                return@launchWhenCreated
            }
            if(response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                adapter.rickAndMorty = response.body()!!
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Response not successful")
            }
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
        }
```

Comment: Json текстом добавьте в вопрос, косяк из-за него

Comment: Не понял тебя, можешь кодом ответить, я новичок и пока не могу понять ответ в таком формате

Comment: Это была просьба добавить информацию в вопрос, а не ответ. Вы запрашиваете страницу https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character. Эта страница возвращает Вам ответ текстом в формате Json. При парсинге этого Json (превращение в класс Kotlin) и происходит ошибка. Получите этот текст, и сравните его структуру со структурой, которую ожидаете (List<RickAndMorty>). Подсказка: там на самом деле нихрена не список